# ORA-02292 when using Hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to implement a delete function but all I get is this ORA-02292 ERROR:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-02292: Integritäts-Constraint (VDMA.FK892DE8B473F40868) verletzt - untergeordneter Datensatz gefunden

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951)
```

I have an Entity (MainEntity) that has an n:m relationship with its child entity.

**For example: A User can have multiple cars, each car can be driven by different users.**

When a User is deleted, I want the associations between the User and the Car to be deleted as well.  That´s why I thought I could do the following :

**User Entity**

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "user_car", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = DATABASE_COLUMN_ID, nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = DATABASE_COLUMN_TYPE_ID,
      nullable = true, updatable = false) })
private Set<UserCar> userCars;
```

**Car Entity**

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "userCars")
  private Set<User> users;
```

The result is :

The tables get created, the data gets persisted - everything works fine.
EXCEPT deleting entries: As soon as I try to delete a User and the User has a car (and therefore a user : car relationship) I do get the errors shown above.

If the user doesn´t have any cars I can delete him without any issues. So the problem must be the constraint in the USER_CAR table.

Comment: What is `UserCar` entity in `private Set<UserCar> userCars;`? Is it a car mapped to something like `CAR` table, and USER_CAR is the junction table between users and cars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear `userCars` as well:

```
user.getUserCars().clear()
```

This will break the association between user and associated cars (it will delete the corresponding records from the junction table).

Also, you don't want `CascadeType.ALL` on many-to-many associations, because it implicitly contains `CascadeType.REMOVE`. Using it means that removal will be cascaded to cars as well, although there are other users who are associated with those cars.

Comment: Before you delete the user.

Comment: Attention, as Hari and aksamit are already stumbled upon it: Why do you have a `ManyToMany` with a in implicit `CascadeType.REMOVE` (in the `cascade=CascadeType.ALL`)? `CascadeType.REMOVE` does only make sense for `OneToX` relations, as it implies removing the referenced entity when the parent entity is removed.

Comment: @TobiasLiefke Your are right, thanks! I didn't notice that the OP uses that. I edited my answer to include that warning as well.

Comment: @Dragan  : Which CasecadeType is the correct then ?

Comment: @TobiasLiefke: Which CascadeType should I use instead ?

Comment: Whichever ones suit your use cases. To include all except `REMOVE`, you could specify `cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH}`. But exclude those that you will not use; `PERSIST` and `MERGE` are often sufficient in most use cases.

Answer (score -1):

Pls make sure you delete the child records, adding the orphanRemoval will help

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade =         CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true)
```

@JoinTable(name = "user_car", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name =     DATABASE_COLUMN_ID, nullable = false, updatable = false) },    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = DATABASE_COLUMN_TYPE_ID,
      nullable = true, updatable = false) })
          private Set userCars;

This will delete all cars assoicated with a user.

Comment: I can see that ican add that property to OneToMany but not ManyToMany relationships ... any alternative ?

Comment: Sorry did not notice it is ManyToMany, Only relationships with single cardinality on the source side can enable orphan removal, which is why the orphanRemoval option is defined on the "@OneToOne" and "@OneToMany" relationship annotations, but on neither of the "@ManyToOne" or "@ManyToMany" annotations.

Comment: Any solution for ManyToMany ?